# Is there a way to compare your currently equipped items with those in the auction house?

Tags: diablo-iii

I'm not seeing a way to do this which makes it hard to decide if I want to buy something for my characters. Ideally I can see the item and then see what items my characters have of the same type almost like comparing and item in inventory.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just select your character on the equipment tab of the auction house and then hover over the icon of any listed item, you'll get the details of the listed item and your equipped item displayed both.

You must hover over the icon, not any other part of the row.

[image]

Comment: I feel like an idiot, I've spent 15 minutes trying to figure this out and you just have to select them on the equipment tag. Thanks.

Comment: The other thing to add to your post, that if you want to compare an item to something that fits in 2 slots (weapons or rings) you can hold alt down. It mentions this in the game but not for the auction house where it still works.

Comment: Is there a way to get the damage/hp/protection #'s like in-game?

Comment: @Drew McGhie No there currently is not. Sometimes you have to guess which weapon is a better upgrade.

Comment: When searching for items on the AH, I also make a note of which item I want to replace on my Character. Then search for items with those stats specifically.

Comment: You  might add to your answer, that, if you want to *find* items similar to one you have, you just right-click the item in the inventory and choose "search similar items"

Answer (score 1):

you can if you link the AH item to one of your mates, then start a game and click on the item you linked.
As in you have to be in game for the stat difference to show

Comment: This is answering a slightly different question, the one at http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/70876/is-there-a-way-to-check-stat-differentials-while-in-the-auction-house