# Is there a way to check stat differentials while in the auction house?

Tags: diablo-iii

[This question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/67556/5291) shows how to compare items in the auction house with what you are wearing, but for me that's not always enough.

When I'm comparing a +damage ring with a +attack speed ring with a +stat ring, I have no idea how it will affect my overall DPS. The tooltips in the auction house don't show the stat differential like items do in-game.

**Is there a way to see the change in Life, Damage and Protection on an item in the auction house before you buy it?**

Comment: Question should be close as there is no longer an auction house for diablo 3.

Comment: @z- Question should not be closed. See [this answer](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/8451/50582) to your own meta question about D3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is now an annoying and tedious way to do this.  Now that you can see the stat differentials of chat linked items **while in a game**, all you have to do is:

- `Shift+Click` the item to copy it to the chat window
- Send it anywhere
- Start a game.
- Once you are in the game, you can click the item from chat and it should show you the differences.

If it does not,  try sending the chat message again while in game.  While this does require you to leave the Auction House, at least it gives you some way to compare those items.  I recommend linking a bunch of items at once so you don't have to go in/out as often.

Answer (score 3):

You can only calculate these bonuses yourself, there is no way to show them the way the in game hud does...

Comment: This answer is outdated as of patch 1.0.5

Comment: @OrigamiRobot Really? I'm not seeing the differences when I hover...

Comment: @CamJackson - See [my answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/90071/9983)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a damage calculator, such as the one over at [DiabloDamageCalculator.com](http://diablodamagecalculator.com/) with the stats you already have on your gear/weapons plus the stats on the piece of gear or weapon you are looking at on the Auction House to estimate what your damage will be if you buy that item.